# How to use Emmet to create consecutive <li>

Tags: phpstorm, emmet

I want create some `<li>` tags like this whit Emmet.

```
<ul>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 2</li>
    <li>List 3</li>
    <li>List 4</li>
    <li>List 5</li>
</ul>
```

I am using PhpStorm.

Comment: So .. use it (Emmet) -- PhpStorm supports it. https://docs.emmet.io/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ul>li{List $@}*5
```

- > means child node
- {} means the node value
- $@ means the index
- and *5 create five times <li>